# url_for appending query string in Pylons

Tags: python, routes, pylons

in routes.py:

```
map.connect("/panel/transaction/list/{count}/",controller='transaction',action='list' , count=0)
map.connect('/panel/transaction/tcard/{key}/{transaction_id}/',controller='transaction',action='tcard' , key='a',transaction_id=0)
```

When i open url like this /panel/transaction/tcard/a/12/

then h.url_for(controller='transaction',action='list',count=0) returning url with query_string form parent map:
 /panel/transaction/list/0/?key=a&transaction_id=12

For what reason h.url_for create url with query_string on the end?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You're experiencing the Route Memory feature of Routes.

http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/urls-routing-and-dispatch.html#route-memory